# What style would you guys say this image is?

Tags: style-identification, style

Does this image fit into any of these styles?

1830 Victoriana
1875 Arts & Crafts Movement
1883 Art Nouveau Movement
1909 Futurism
1919 Bauhaus
1925 Art Deco
1945 International Typographic Style (also called Swiss International Style)
1950 Figurative Typography
1966 Psychedelic Art
1976 Punk
1990 Deconstruction

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Hi Thomas Mire, based on your list I would say no (but I don't any definitive reason why, more so an opinion). This style reminds me of house music flyers or a music festival flyer. May I ask how you came up with this list and why the 2 might be connected (Genres vs image)? That could help me and other users better answer your question.

Comment: Why do you think this visual styles are all there is? Do you have other options?

Comment: I am taking a Typography class. I am trying to settle on an art style for my final project. I must pic from the list above. I came up with this image because it was given to the class as an example by the teacher. It is an online Typography class. I have written the teacher but i have not received a response as of yet. Thats why i came to you guys with the question. I cannot see that it fits into any of the above styles either.

Comment: I don't know the project scope but the entire Jan 22... headline is just bad typography in my opinion.

Comment: The closest descriptive general categories are: "3D extruded" and "letterpress type sculpture"

Comment: @ryan: I don't know if it is "bad" but it is certainly a bad pairing: everything they tagged on kills the three dimensional effect. This might be OK in concept, but it comes off as accidental.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No I don't think it fits into any of the styles you listed.

Road textures and paint splatters are usually associated with grunge and/or graffiti as far as I know. Which makes sense since Berkvisual is a graffiti artist.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I figured as much, but was looking for other opinions.